# How to reset auto increment field in a ActiveRecord migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rails-migrations

In my migration I have:

```
def up
   MyModel.destroy_all
   MyModel.create!({:id=>1,:name=>'foo'})
   MyModel.create!({:id=>2,:name=>'fooBar'})
   MyModel.create!({:id=>3,:name=>'fooNull'})
end
```

because I need to override data that was already on my_models table

But Even though I'm specifying the `id` on MySQL it continues the numbering from the position it already was.

I need to rest the counter on the auto increment for `id` to have only this 3 new records with that id values trough Active Record migration on my Ruby on Rails application.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You have 2 separate issues.  One is that you are trying to specify the id with mass assignment, rails won't allow you to do that.  See [Overriding id on create in ActiveRecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431617/overriding-id-on-create-in-activerecord) for a way to do that.

The other issue is that the auto-increment isn't resetting.  Each DBMS has a unique way of setting an increment counter, and rails doesn't give you a generic way to access them, although it is implemented for some of them (not MySQL), see [Rails way to reset seed on id field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097052/rails-way-to-reset-seed-on-id-field)

So you'll need to run the MySQL specific SQL for this, which is something like:

```
ALTER TABLE my_models AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

This should reset to the number after the largest id in your table (1 if there aren't any)

Answer (score 20):

**PostgreSQL:**

```
ModelName.connection.execute('ALTER SEQUENCE model_name_id_seq RESTART WITH 1')
```

For example, resetting the auto increment field for the User model would look like:

```
User.connection.execute('ALTER SEQUENCE users_id_seq RESTART WITH 1')
```

**MySQL:**

```
ModelName.connection.execute('ALTER TABLE model_names AUTO_INCREMENT = 1')
```

For example, resetting the auto increment field for the User model would look like:

```
User.connection.execute('ALTER TABLE users AUTO_INCREMENT = 1')
```

Comment: ALTER SEQUENCE is not supported by MySQL

Comment: The question is about MySQL not PostgreSQL. Although your answer is generally useful, it's better to keep answers relevant to the original question.

Comment: Added instructions for MySQL

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone else wonders how to do this with MYSQL: here is the code one would use in the migration in order to reset the auto increment for a table:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('ALTER TABLE foo_bars AUTO_INCREMENT = 1')
```

- Where `foo_bars` would be the table name whose auto_increment you are resetting.

I figured this out thanks to the answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544429/reseting-primary-key-id-in-rails).

Answer (score 0):

for sqlite3 it would be:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('delete from sqlite_sequence where name="your_tablename"')
```