# Is there a way to reset only a part of the DB in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was wondering if it's possible to reset just a part of the DB to free up the IDs that were taken by previous entries. For example, let's say your DB is filled with info about **users** and about **admins**. Then I'd like to delete all admins or users and get back to filling the DB up back from ID 1 depending on which ones I've removed. Is this even possible without doing `rake db:reset` and resetting the whole DB ?

Comment: Did you filled the database using a seed.rb task?

Comment: Not too relevant, let's say that I didn't use seed.rb and I just want to make the IDs go back to 1 and delete all entered data for only a **part** of the DB. It seems to me that that's not manageable but still, worth a shot to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just delete the records first. Then you have to look for the DBspecific command that resets the autoincrement counter. This post shows how to do that (they do it in a migration although I think the rails console would work as well:

[How to reset auto increment field in a ActiveRecord migration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853826/how-to-reset-auto-increment-field-in-a-activerecord-migration)

Comment: Hmm, I wrote a helper method to use in my view as a kind of 'Reset' button but the DB seems to disagree with the syntax. I'll have to look into the DB commands some more. But this seems like something I wanted to do, thanks.