# After importing data in PostgreSQL, duplicate key value violates unique constraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I recently migrated my rails app to PostgreSQL in order to take advantage of fulltext search.

Since the migration coincided with moving to a new webhost, the steps for migration were:

1. Deploy the application and db:create/db:schema:load on the new server, with appropriate database.yml file
2. mysqldump data only from existing MySQL production database
3. import data into PostgreSQL database

The application is running successfully but the issue comes when trying to add new content to the database. For example, when I run the rake task to update my twitter feed:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "twitter_feeds_pkey" DETAIL:  Key (id)=(3) already exists.
```

This also happens for all other models, creating new articles, users etc. In development I can see that posting the insert statement n+1 times will successfully save the record without error.

My question is: **How do I tell PostgreSQL to start adding indexes sequentially from the existing data?**

I've read the `REINDEX` page but don't think that is really the operation I'm looking for.

Comment: Does the table contain serials / sequences , used as a PK?

Comment: This question should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244243/how-to-reset-postgres-primary-key-sequence-when-it-falls-out-of-sync

Comment: Damn, I should have known there was prior art, before digging it up from my "personal archive".

Comment: Thank you for the linked question, the language I failed to summon from my brain was 'primary key sequence is not in sync with my table rows'

Comment: This question is answered extremely well here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244243/how-to-reset-postgres-primary-key-sequence-when-it-falls-out-of-sync

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If the schema contains serial or sequence columns, you should reset these to the max value that occurs in the corresponding column. (normally you should not import the serials from a file, but give them the freedom to autoincrement.)

For all imported tables you should identify the sequence fields and run the following code on them. (substitute your schema name for "sch", your table name for "mytable" and your id column name for "id")

```
WITH mx AS ( SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM sch.mytable)
SELECT setval('sch.mytable_id_seq', mx.id) AS curseq
FROM mx
        ;
```

Answer (score 32):

In Rails you can use the command

> `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reset_pk_sequence!('users')`

to bring the primary key index for the User table in sync again.

Comment: Is this method applicable for mysql2 adapter?

Comment: Worked for me with Postgres adapter

Comment: @roarfromror, no, reset_pk_sequence! is only defined for the Postgres connection adapter (in Rails 3 & 4 at least).

Comment: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "increment_by" does not exist

Answer (score 5):

You can automate wildplasser's solution so that all sequences are synchronized with the current maximum value of their associated column:

```
do
$block$
declare 
  r        record;
  stmt     text;
  max_id   integer;
begin
  for r in (
              select *
              from (
                select table_schema, 
                       table_name, 
                       column_name, 
                       pg_get_serial_sequence(table_schema||'.'||table_name, column_name) as col_sequence
                from information_schema.columns
                where table_schema not in ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
              ) t
              where col_sequence is not null
        ) 
  loop
    stmt := 'select coalesce(max('||r.column_name||'), 0) + 1 from '||r.table_schema||'.'||r.table_name;
    execute stmt into max_id;
    raise notice 'Next ID for %.%.% is %', r.table_schema, r.table_name, r.column_name, max_id;
    perform setval(r.col_sequence, max_id); 
  end loop;
end;
$block$
```

Note that this will only work if the columns have been defined as `serial`, `bigserial` or have been made the "owner" of a sequence.

Comment: Great. I had a similar thing handy but I did not want to spoil the OP's editing party ;-) BTW: you could add a few quote_identifier() functions to the names.

Comment: Thank you, I'm always a fan of automation.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I did not know about the pg_get_serial_sequence() function. Comes in handy, avoiding the  joining of three(?) additional catalogs.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is remove the primary key (id) from the columns (or don't dump the id). So your data would look like

```
INSERT INTO book (name, price) VALUES ('Alchemist' , 10);
```

instead of

```
INSERT INTO book (id, name, price) VALUES (1 , 'Alchemist' , 10);
```

This way, you won't have to reset the primary key after loading initial data